# Logging in with an SSH key doesn't work on Git Bash but does in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: bash, ssh, digital-ocean, git-bash, openssh

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04) to set up my first DigitalOcean droplet, and I just generated a Key Pair for Public Key Authentication. After using `ssh-copy-id` (from Git Bash, since the command isn't available in Command Prompt) to add the key to my Droplet, I can SSH into my droplet just fine from Command Prompt.

However, when I try to SSH from Git Bash, it still prompts me for my password! I've checked, and the SSH keys exist on my Droplet and on my computer. What's the problem?

Comment: I don't believe Git Bash load private key automatically unless you put it on the predefined path by SSH. Have you tried adding your key to the agent manually?

Comment: @PraveenP No, how would I do that? What's the predefined path?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can load the key by running `ssh-add path-to-private-key`

```
ssh-add /Users/ben/id_rsa
```

The predefined path is `UserHome -> .ssh -> private-key & public-key`

```
/c/Users/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa
/c/Users/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

There are restrictions to the name of the file as well as the location. Following are the known filenames that SSH agent will look for that I can think on top of my head:

- identity
- id_dsa
- id_rsa

These names are generally determined by the **Type** you've used to generate them. Most commonly used is ***rsa*** which creates *id_rsa* and *id_rsa.pub*.

Also, most Windows user uses [Putty](https://www.putty.org/) as the SSH daemon. It works pretty well. The best thing about that is it has GUI to set the specific private key so it loads that every time without having to do any of the above stuff.

Comment: Whenever I run `ssh-add` in Git Bash, it prints this message: `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`.

Comment: Oh, that's because you have no "active agent" you need to run `eval \`ssh-agent\`` first which will print something like this **Agent pid 21561**. Then you can run the rest of the commands. If that doesn't work try this instead `eval $(ssh-agent)`. That is the Linux one, one above is Unix (MacOSX)